# String pass as array in andFilterWhere() in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

One **String** like below:

```
$condition = "['or',['LIKE','name','index'],['=','type',1]]";
```

**get condition string from Database**

want to convert in **array** so, it can pass in below statement:

```
$query->andFilterWhere($condition);
```

Comment: You have to write your own method to change the string into array. I'm just curious how did you start with string like that and not array?

Comment: @Bizley It's Specified that string is comming from DB and not from any function or such.

Comment: The comment by @Bizley  is right .. you have to wrote a proper function for change the string in the array you need .. start looking  at the pattern of the string ..and using explode  for get the part you need for poplulate the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `eval()` (not specific to yii) :

```
$condition = "['or',['LIKE','name','index'],['=','type',1]]";
eval("\$condition = $condition;");
```

Read more about [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Comment: Friendly reminder that using eval() is **very dangerous**.

Comment: Yes,That work thank you but, Why use '\' before $condition in eval method?
elaborate it.

Comment: Because it will be like writing the following code : `$condition = ['or',['LIKE','name','index'],['=','type',1]];`